# Breakpoint at method signatures slows down debugger

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jvm, breakpoints

I'm using IntelliJ, and when I'm debbuging, if I put the breakpoint on the line of the **signature** of the method, and run the debugger, a warning pops up telling me:

```
Method breakpoint may dramatically slow down debugging
```

but if I put it on any line inside the method, it's fine. Why?

Comment: I've noticed this in Eclipse too. Not the warning, just the dramatic slowdown.

Answer (score 2):

Design of JVM makes it expensive to evaluate when breakpoints are set on methods.
To verify that you don't have any method breakpoints open .idea/workspace.xml file in the project root directory (or .iws file if you are using the old project format) and look for any breakpoints inside the method_breakpoints node.
Refer [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544799-Java-slow-performance-or-hangups-when-starting-debugger-and-stepping).

Comment: You're not really answering the question.

Comment: I do realize it is expensive to evaluate when breakpoints are set on the signature of the method, but my question was more about the reason (inner workings) why the JVM works that way.